# Optimizing custom fill of a 2d array in Julia

Tags: arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array, julia

I'm a little new to Julia and am trying to use the `fill!` [method](http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/function/fill-exclamation) to improve code performance on Julia. Currently, I read a 2d array from a file say `read_array` and perform row-operations on it to get a `processed_array` as follows:

```
function preprocess(matrix)
# Initialise
    processed_array= Array{Float64,2}(undef, size(matrix)); 
#first row of processed_array is the difference of first two row of matrix
    processed_array[1,:] = (matrix[2,:] .- matrix[1,:]) ; 
#last row of processed_array  is difference of last two rows of matrix
    processed_array[end,:] = (matrix[end,:] .- matrix[end-1,:]); 
#all other rows of processed_array  is the mean-difference of other two rows
    processed_array[2:end-1,:] = (matrix[3:end,:] .- matrix[1:end-2,:]) .*0.5 ; 
    return processed_array
end
```

However, when I try using the `fill!` method I get a `MethodError`.

```
processed_array = copy(matrix)
fill!(processed_array [1,:],d[2,:]-d[1,:])
```

`MethodError: Cannot convert an object of type Matrix{Float64} to an object of type Float64`

I'll be glad if someone can tell me what I'm missing and also suggest a method to optimize the code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`fill!(A, x)` is used to fill the array `A` with a unique value `x`, so it's not what you want anyway.

What you could do for a little performance gain is to broadcast the assignments. That is, use `.=` instead of `=`. If you want, you can also use the `@.` macro to automatically add dots everywhere for you (for maybe cleaner/easier-to-read code):

```
function preprocess(matrix)
    out = Array{Float64,2}(undef, size(matrix))
    @views @. out[1,:] = matrix[2,:] - matrix[1,:]
    @views @. out[end,:] = matrix[end,:] - matrix[end-1,:]
    @views @. out[2:end-1,:] = 0.5 * (matrix[3:end,:] - matrix[1:end-2,:]) 
    return out
end
```

For optimal performance, I think you probably want to write the loops explicitly and use multithreading with a package like [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl) for example.

PS: Note that in your code comments you wrote "cols" instead of "rows", and you wrote "mean" but take a difference. (Not sure it was intentional.)

Comment: Adding `@views` in front of this will help -- otherwise every slice here makes a new `Array`.

Comment: Thanks! Added it to the answer!

Comment: Hi @Benoit! This worked. Thanks! Yes, it should be `rows`, not `columns` (I edited this now) Also, yeah, I am actually computing the mean difference.

Comment: BTW, if interested in package solutions, mine lets you write `@tullio out[r,c] = (matrix[r+1,c] - matrix[r-1,c]) / 2` for the last line, which is closer to what you'd write on paper, and further from Matlab. (Xref   https://github.com/mcabbott/Tullio.jl/issues/97 for a hurdle to writing the other lines the same way.)